# Nokia S-40 LWUIT list scrolling issue

Tags: list, java-me, scroll, lwuit, nokia-s40

I've a `List` in my app and when I do the scroll over all the screen, the `List` use to set in the first element, I meant the user is sent to the beginning of the list if I make the gesture painted with the red arrow.

Anybody knows anything about this issue?

ADD

[Video](http://www.swfme.com/view/1263042)

[image: List Photo]

Comment: You mean that you "jump" to begining oo end of your list? what is the red arrow?

Comment: Yes. The red arrow is the gesture that the user does with the finger. He scrolls from the down point to the top of the screen. At first the list scrolls ok, but when the top point is reached the form auto scroll to the begginin of the form

Comment: maybe that can help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818255/lwuit-scroll-jumping-issue/13800659#13800659

Comment: No, sorry this answer don't help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the S40 port since I'm not sure what they did there. Many of these things relate to placing a List within a scrollable container rather than placing it in the center of a non-scrollable container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Shai, but this is not the problem, because the Nokia S40 samples have the same issue, and there you only can find a list in a BoxLayout Y Form.

Comment: It would seem the Nokia guys made the same mistake. You should place the list in the center of a non-scrollable border layout. Not in a Box Y layout. It works partially in Box Y layout but there are "issues" such as these.